# How to set specific acceleration?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics

I am making a platformer game where my player is a box. This box will have different mass and according to that mass ı want it to accelerate differently. For example if it has 3 mass I want to reach its maximum speed slower and I want the acceleration time to be much more than it has 1 mass.
Another question is, I want my character to lose its speed faster than how it gains it. For example if it reaches max speed in 2 seconds, it will stop in 1 second.

I tried to use AddForce component in order to move my character and I don't know how to set max speed and acceleration.

Comment: [AddForce](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddForce.html) with the default forcemode `ForceMode.Force` already takes mass into account. Same force applied to mass 3 will cause smaller acceleration than to mass 1. To achieve faster slow down you will have to implement a stopping force that decelerates when appropriate (i.e. not accelerating and velocity magnitude over 0 in the opposite direction).

Answer (score 0):

```
rigidbody.AddForce(force, forceMode);
```

That will allow you to apply the force to the object and it will move according to the laws of physics, considering mass, surface and air drag and other stuff that happens to it.

If you need to limit the acceleration and/or max speed and don't need the object to interact with complex environment, you may want to get a formula of acceleration form the school book and code your own movement logic:

```
Vector3 acceleration = force * (time * time) / mass;
currentVelocity += acceleration;
```

Limiting the maximum velocity with rigidbodies is a bit more complex and requires more tuning to your situation, but in general you can get current `rigidbody.velocity`, measure its magnitude, and if it approaches the maximum allowed speed just scale down the force to reduce acceleration, effectively making the force = 0 when the speed is at maximum. Of course you need to remember that in case of using physics there could be other forces affecting object's acceleration like gravity and you must consider them to get desired effect and not breaking everything apart.